# Node HTTP-Proxy to HTTPS server with client certificate

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy, electron

Our servers rely on client certificates to validate access. Right now neither Electron nor NW.JS seem to support client certificates yet, which prevents us from creating an application that can connect to our server.

After doing some research, it seems like it should be possible to use **node-http-proxy** to setup a proxy server that all of the communications go through. It looks like it's possible to introduce the client certificate through this method, essentially:

Client Request -> Proxy Server (adds client certificate) -> Server (response) -> Proxy Server -> Client

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible or not, but that's what I'm aiming for. This is the code I have so far:

```
var cert = fs.readFileSync ("./cert.p12");
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer ({
    target: {
        host: "devserver",
        protocol: "https:",
        port: 443,
        pfx: cert,
        passphrase: "certificatepassword"   
    },
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    xfwd: true,
    //agent: https.globalAgent
    agent: false
}).listen (8080);
```

PFX is a loaded in .p12 file. When I set this as the proxy server in Firefox I get "Secure Connection Failed" when attempting to reach our development server. I've tried a bunch of different methods with no better results and I'm not sure how to continue from this point...

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: I have similar requirement.  Any success getting it to work?

Comment: @1001b I never got it working in the sense of the original question. My company ended up doing a bounty for client certificates in Electron, which resolved my original issue without the need of a proxy server. I don't think a proxy server the way I wanted it would have worked. You could certainly try briangreenery's answer below, but I don't know if it will work well in a browser situation like Electron.

Answer (score 12):

It's totally possible to do this. This pretty much just involves setting up the `target` option correctly. Like, most of the work is just doing:

```
  var options = {
    target: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3002,
      protocol: 'https:',
      key: clientKey,
      cert: clientCert,
      ca: caCert,
    },
    changeOrigin: true
  };
```

Here's a complete example that demonstrates this. It creates an https server on port 3002 that requires a client certificate, and an http server on port 3001 that proxies to the https server.

```
var http = require('http'),
  https = require('https'),
  httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var caCert =
  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' +
  'MIIDajCCAlICCQDgeRZY85PN7TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB2MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV\n' +
  'UzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEh\n' +
  'MB8GA1UEChMYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkgTHRkMRcwFQYDVQQDEw5EZW1v\n' +
  'IEF1dGhvcml0eTAgFw0xNTA3MDQyMTQxNDlaGA8yMTE1MDYxMDIxNDE0OVowdjEL\n' +
  'MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG\n' +
  'cmFuY2lzY28xITAfBgNVBAoTGEludGVybmV0IFdpZGdpdHMgUHR5IEx0ZDEXMBUG\n' +
  'A1UEAxMORGVtbyBBdXRob3JpdHkwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEK\n' +
  'AoIBAQC+kP1Zn05sixEGRQ9waRZtAEb2MBYtrebUkh6ogNiVCFfo6qWp9gmqeucU\n' +
  'PGl4cEMyVIJNqvURFsYwTmMQwGsoT7ek9rgGcdr/DSrqClq+micRalORrmYzUZ1W\n' +
  'cY5GwYdLv+fFbOKb4/sQY5XnS7pUp23Pc+AIAB7O29gWdDcPF1wuA3NU+rvuopkN\n' +
  'pYN5FPFViqOAxHffT3bAFF3LAPN3YS0zqjXNlM2zM58kfyRvMvE9fotbjfX8LWms\n' +
  'Je6kD4AYmcehcHvkBeKyvKa5Zh90uNdgC6wmtUHZ+sqt5a02mE+uHongLCMME3bP\n' +
  '2F+ov3fbEsPng4bLcgsLy/R4MB0pAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAJ2K\n' +
  'RscR2O97SW+hnWBrHgNGHsMvsFel0Ne2X6IJ7AJmir0eIVgG22U9BkevMKvC9dOZ\n' +
  '9k9sgQsIVSvcMCIXZaCMEvTli65SxHE55OJdWIeBn/6vNysX2gSDxDmxGUnWpHHe\n' +
  'JALL57Fp4GKAvEKnnvvM7WyACReluDTwweQn2W4cXwaOrs37cF22CaQljJfdhZfS\n' +
  'KkJ/R9OGW0fSefebH6ofsVWD2aOzWPGj2mIxQhcjoa1XTEZu37Ab0290KIWUOMCA\n' +
  'XNWIq782dRGWOpm653cvdgkDijeU821dddJR7qb/WrTODhnI3N28lxC6kfl3Wawr\n' +
  'vnEg2nF657AcrlZHImM=\n' +
  '-----END CERTIFICATE-----';

var serverKey =
  '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n' +
  'MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAwtM92Lm1dtFkDHmFxIrTL3fJZcVejTfxJqtvL931iF7jRaIJ\n' +
  '6T1kRibkz6Lj6/87JuGzBXBJo9nv6Faycep20bUetDZ6TpO0r5YhjpZiKKGuVy35\n' +
  'Tj2/KuR0gM/Ift0N9+8eqZ+09cFEqDywjzbnSsnNYEuEcKDnSxjyy339O2QAl3Aw\n' +
  'BuTdhP1VsXsvvtzQEepzb/rj46hsGSd+regEItKJjQjb/Bh76kQ+4Ab1CRq+ZSei\n' +
  '5wrEFSpivPqSDXqgIzxCqCuFyQu4x13w22Guf3dzPVf5GsiYxED1t7c2O3reISrb\n' +
  'dMS70njU9pca9UlmIXFnue8TIzZLOcZeXBVZhQIDAQABAoIBAQCMpNCd9xqgBvMx\n' +
  '6jx+MTXZq6DxXjUuvzbQkqv2o0ZQRyfMqfh7rz0HQ6akmlPtl1hNblu9Tl1q8ra1\n' +
  'RHkXsYpLQ3RB5p4OwaSLqVbaR4ffCzD/cInsSLkLrtbH8rgrlUszNCUvkMKjMv1s\n' +
  'cjuHd7wrClm/7WRTpmSymvUToAVCbGDWtrj1aPILqdlNI8VGhrUiEO5ukecnHLhS\n' +
  'EQJgxPzQkJnSdpJAtJrFEErvaoPoNfZl7vcqEAFtKahqAZEXhWLy1n/61kqO+NGe\n' +
  'rbF3fLikdj8cAqmOOLuy8BZxUGTkoE7/7tTEPqrf8QR2R6bSdXBq4zPO/v9+we62\n' +
  'e4dM1NThAoGBAO0hjAeGrtxqQEUNaFFqkCZCoTR395E/QjBLHxpp5DfAQE7jFMSO\n' +
  'qK9Fy98YZqKJeLOMBodKoeQt/Hd9Q2PPaQFr7Elj9lN6DhAlV5jLX5ZoWeazRf7R\n' +
  'yq8IyYP61ZwVcInzrbwaYCheT++WvR+ccV8FG4LfO8THuh6BBNh8nKrNAoGBANJT\n' +
  '6DfeCy9AaReB7gy85O5JhTVA2qZZr1V8kX5HDytNSDW+s9qGb7MM2oITiOg3lKyE\n' +
  'yToqsOtjwwmk8dihC1iZXC0u5dYrJtgVsE7pWzqXAU5M8uILYW7AtgPcG+pYUBmu\n' +
  '9XF0L03Tur9Wv+Owhbi/K8E0nblufzwaWljbWlmZAoGBAM9R7y19UVAgDQTSTgww\n' +
  'kMsCohJPeMEif2ndo9niDse3bAIMg1G+MDjdWvs4SDN+4WqI2ARc+eGXWw3VFKAk\n' +
  '7HdztegMX4ZoRfdTzpwl4vKLVV5gCqhZH02c7yJWoX+PNw9FXvYAUWW530Vnkv4a\n' +
  'NvyOaJkpNwY6YLzerC/h8s9ZAoGAZfP2ZN5lXYpDZvm8gsAt2LQati2xz2E59J5l\n' +
  'iGi5mavkjOjcFdmE264nXVZKzwXiM55KTL/U8sVxDYO/F9s4vMHaRKyvDJnuQmCB\n' +
  'Dj9f0Y7ROzthoOETYbRYhpZzka0tZsXAhDZll7xCke1jJuOyblN8yjLPIcvGMUQ0\n' +
  '902dBkECgYEAv2+Lk+eM326snmetHWKRbgPsWtOVsU2L2DkRsgAXUPjQ1VJSD5df\n' +
  'yw+L/F3ubSpqBYNdV8MmD+eBp3bboY+QLpHwyTrGIhG8fjeFLVhGYvwkpko+bjyi\n' +
  '7lS5/+rZsjHQSNmm8WdOdZYx4cZqYlmXb7tMnTct4DkaslD2KhYeLjY=\n' +
  '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

var serverCert =
  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' +
  'MIIDZTCCAk0CCQC+bRt5zDRK+jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB2MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV\n' +
  'UzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEh\n' +
  'MB8GA1UEChMYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkgTHRkMRcwFQYDVQQDEw5EZW1v\n' +
  'IEF1dGhvcml0eTAgFw0xNTA3MDQyMTU1NThaGA8yMTE1MDYxMDIxNTU1OFowcTEL\n' +
  'MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG\n' +
  'cmFuY2lzY28xITAfBgNVBAoTGEludGVybmV0IFdpZGdpdHMgUHR5IEx0ZDESMBAG\n' +
  'A1UEAxMJbG9jYWxob3N0MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA\n' +
  'wtM92Lm1dtFkDHmFxIrTL3fJZcVejTfxJqtvL931iF7jRaIJ6T1kRibkz6Lj6/87\n' +
  'JuGzBXBJo9nv6Faycep20bUetDZ6TpO0r5YhjpZiKKGuVy35Tj2/KuR0gM/Ift0N\n' +
  '9+8eqZ+09cFEqDywjzbnSsnNYEuEcKDnSxjyy339O2QAl3AwBuTdhP1VsXsvvtzQ\n' +
  'Eepzb/rj46hsGSd+regEItKJjQjb/Bh76kQ+4Ab1CRq+ZSei5wrEFSpivPqSDXqg\n' +
  'IzxCqCuFyQu4x13w22Guf3dzPVf5GsiYxED1t7c2O3reISrbdMS70njU9pca9Ulm\n' +
  'IXFnue8TIzZLOcZeXBVZhQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQA1ZguJfw+4\n' +
  'ktLmz4WdigSVspbkdtqLzPqkfQ1O8qwFqn60JTMnAALWxT+qt+6aLxWLKykOfzNL\n' +
  'p3MKgY/zjZ721YkHxknHw7UBEykwW2fUY33+1WW/IzkpMMp8FW8BwaGRqD+b2RUk\n' +
  'w2+HBCqa4xjESZjjAlsh+Z9W+dKRK4+B76U+2lqyHMKRFDDKKj7rK/0n7afZP9EO\n' +
  'kpc5566sUseRLZVgd27YfxBXmT3zhOWHJjqzor/Iya6O2kdDxqJ355Q6n9HprPe+\n' +
  '6RwmMfRbgDpTkkbuniXhJrRBnSLyFjPgdJCOHSfHCGR+i0Q8HOAxzWHpvJaT8q26\n' +
  '3pVDsVCgsgUI\n' +
  '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n';

var clientKey =
  '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n' +
  'MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA7Gc7QlrFW8XikIfMsqL/wcxn6pS2AZmNNEUEqS4H2wtfZP6U\n' +
  'w8JeDACUGMkgelt/5HisbZgO0RnlJ+0gXZqWKV96n/OGrB8ju1C/6P6P9lkcYByZ\n' +
  'KLF9rAiNcL5dy6VSAPTvokCL+5XZl1yjBTSeJjXTocjLVM6IB5dMO+GyFuFkaZUU\n' +
  '4CHtAKEyE+nQ+9uOmDQfB5Ijp1KZFN+U3CE99Wel8FEno1QKjlXAGk8hiIaW3nDX\n' +
  'YmRxwVUajDfUvJ3hpzIu0zOZf4oVAPt+FozK4zaXvg0E71kNJooYrcyr7dUD6Mkm\n' +
  'xg8MJrgQnRPlYzhldEZYOG1su0BrpCnOjIA75wIDAQABAoIBAQDe/eVlCvBdSAUV\n' +
  '5jMNUjnEGcbv/MTOL4SFiJED8JqSYWDjiEzVdzN1SNppotaS9FpoLfggDK31SeLh\n' +
  'zYiZIueAMUMfO/yNwXXYDCxqYC1158qfUnqaaworS4n3jmo1XUVEB8c/GnmwoEI2\n' +
  'x7gygdaoHl/5nMlHvuWLm4jad2OgtbyxLVW/BG8d2f9OG1P4N2inE8kZVfkDvX21\n' +
  'qnlFf8HWUGpMxHwjcNN6DD+42kD1pKqRVkHCGXHRztOHRhr2VzDPssSLU7rd/Yjv\n' +
  'hPcUj34J+2WL+rpfKNFsDeqA/eA03whID1AOaPKGfjGklsbvzoBf4a/6CkWBomxu\n' +
  'IRh9XGnBAoGBAP82BkTO1g4lD8SuSAlQAX1Ob/SiF+ps+Cvhqz2evG9Dkd1LnC2O\n' +
  'CGYWJUyNUMQLsT+E3pNYilMgfY+fZILD8Pzl7hsPCF2DKiiQDhdGaKWbAgYMCxrY\n' +
  'Ye8cRbHTBmLrHOoa1H2JQzUm4Q8JvRjWDQWlZayVw9nxuEw3ufeI1KbhAoGBAO0i\n' +
  'UojwLde72LuPa+l02h4mAYDQFQArKmd9H2p71V/GQQDN9SGsMJfOdEAyP9Md2qlj\n' +
  'vy8jAzy3dUXAWwDJeFeUls/KFM4hnkfqBK9FsE7FHchQr5M1nfov0lYe5gjLmH7A\n' +
  'k9IKheR12K/X1vocEcb4W+X9M+4drOulFML7WePHAoGBAJ4xL5uRFe/4mxiP6wkS\n' +
  'tYmliBH8M5TU7NPOcyWj8iuJl62zQ2CdbKlSytXztn9+u+SiiJCOzlcOiaXv6A6C\n' +
  'RCuOnpPZMpc8SXKRMJrOwuj79zomVu/R9oqPXMgIBSplkCuwa8xQu/8DVXfL0pHF\n' +
  'hJbeWfKrdpXulg1wcW51O1MhAoGBAN13e6vG3JmqJ41sMjVz263igu7h52sj5VOH\n' +
  'yQpzIuFy0AzHTZQoM63jtDCsfW1XaXtf3BNS2Ngg4tbFAnjmsIzjCkKAEhQ904yI\n' +
  'Y92p8TJv6BPIP2H15lfdx8yEyQQX2ZEvnB7Dky6+XSRFKdKm2neARpuycYiGkJP3\n' +
  'tj8v7lDLAoGBAJLnvMH3bmzezgpQHZ2hlQ58nrHfBcD2wrILaXylsUgA4ddjWhAP\n' +
  'iSe8ie3UEkHjzSWRzj4cQvgZjqdgScg4XVMxMnaxUia5yVVJAWtLmoCFTjT/ZJgM\n' +
  'MsS2LGlPYBwDeHW7i7vYwMX8aU0huBpo/CxZnB8BzJgqj/NSEAtclBux\n' +
  '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n';

var clientCert =
  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' +
  'MIIDZTCCAk0CCQC+bRt5zDRK+zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADB2MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV\n' +
  'UzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNjbzEh\n' +
  'MB8GA1UEChMYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0cyBQdHkgTHRkMRcwFQYDVQQDEw5EZW1v\n' +
  'IEF1dGhvcml0eTAgFw0xNTA3MDQyMTU3MjJaGA8yMTE1MDYxMDIxNTcyMlowcTEL\n' +
  'MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBG\n' +
  'cmFuY2lzY28xITAfBgNVBAoTGEludGVybmV0IFdpZGdpdHMgUHR5IEx0ZDESMBAG\n' +
  'A1UEAxMJbG9jYWxob3N0MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA\n' +
  '7Gc7QlrFW8XikIfMsqL/wcxn6pS2AZmNNEUEqS4H2wtfZP6Uw8JeDACUGMkgelt/\n' +
  '5HisbZgO0RnlJ+0gXZqWKV96n/OGrB8ju1C/6P6P9lkcYByZKLF9rAiNcL5dy6VS\n' +
  'APTvokCL+5XZl1yjBTSeJjXTocjLVM6IB5dMO+GyFuFkaZUU4CHtAKEyE+nQ+9uO\n' +
  'mDQfB5Ijp1KZFN+U3CE99Wel8FEno1QKjlXAGk8hiIaW3nDXYmRxwVUajDfUvJ3h\n' +
  'pzIu0zOZf4oVAPt+FozK4zaXvg0E71kNJooYrcyr7dUD6Mkmxg8MJrgQnRPlYzhl\n' +
  'dEZYOG1su0BrpCnOjIA75wIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQBDu0nppbbO\n' +
  'tPweh4LiHlk4efjiepWTLolD7FHyj1c5cCg4Ml3+XmRd3jTvXEgqMKsw4OYQsGFy\n' +
  'pfV5W2ehwQnGEBtgGAixMAjj6+GTk53oYRjwW8QxM4MaxJio7guPavvjtUoLR5mf\n' +
  'vMtRw90zI75wB0U+D4c1AHF5LxRoSQN/n1bN0NStxgPKEWQdvqXwo3G5u/dibjC3\n' +
  '7iYFI2XhKHg5FBG0xrrA9xArJigA1TS3yq5tAFLOR22wla/fSqlxV3mCkUfJCKka\n' +
  'jUa7eC1K/+0IAssrazo/ND2H5brcmGXvJaiNPRAjrxPF32DqpwzVNcspJ7KzCWif\n' +
  'immNPLi3ksvI\n' +
  '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n';

// Create an HTTPS server on port 3002 that requires a client certificate.

var serverOptions = {
  key: serverKey,
  cert: serverCert,
  ca: caCert,
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true
};

var server = https.createServer(serverOptions, function(req, res) {
  res.end('it works!');
});

server.listen(3002, function() {
  console.log('https server on port 3002');
});

// Create a plain http server on port 3001 that uses http-proxy to forward to
// the https server on port 3002.

var proxy = httpProxy.createServer();

// https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/734
proxy.on('proxyRes', function(proxyRes, req, res) {
  if (res.shouldKeepAlive) {
    proxyRes.headers.connection = 'keep-alive';
  }
});

var httpServer = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var options = {
    target: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3002,
      protocol: 'https:',
      key: clientKey,
      cert: clientCert,
      ca: caCert,
    },
    changeOrigin: true
  };

  proxy.web(req, res, options, function(err) {
    console.log('oh nooooo: ' + err.toString());

    if (!res.headersSent) {
      res.statusCode = 502;
      res.end('bad gateway');
    }
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3001, function() {
  console.log('proxy server on port 3001');
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this if you rewrite the url for the proxy? For instance, a ui hits `/api/entity` and I proxy to `/api/v1/entity`. I've done this by concatenating the url myself, but if I use target as an object, is there a way to do this?

Comment: very complete example, I think it deserves a whole article by itself.
could you add the commands you used to create all the certs and keys? that would be pretty useful

Comment: I tried to directly access the secured server using curl, but it doesn't recognize the certs and keys. I just copied the content (without the js code, like `' + \n' `) to text files, and I try to run it with: `curl -v -i -k https://localhost:3002/my/own/path?q=me --key client_key.pem --cert client_cert.pem --cacert ca_cert.pem`, it gives me: * schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (e.g. handshake failed)

Comment: Feel like I'm missing something - in practice, the http server won't have access to the client public key, that's... for the client only, isn't it?